# is there a way to automate symbology in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I would like to know if there is some way to automate symbology based on my attributes. I have a list of zipcodes and a column which contains ID-codes of waterstations delivering water in that area. If zipcodes only have one water station delivering water, the column is filled with one ID. But some zip codes have several water stations delivering there. The column cell is then filled with several ID's (see image). Is there a way to give a specific color to an ID? For instance: ID 32.06 gets a brown color, ID 32.09 gets a yellow color. If a zip codes have both stations, the polygons fills a mix of yellow and brown lines. If a zipcode has only one of the two, it fills the polygon with either brown or yellow (see image).

I can do this manually but there are over 400 possibilities which makes this a very time consuming activity.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a third field and use field calculator to assign a value of 1 to zip codes with 1 station, 2 with 2 stations, and 3 with three stations or more.  Then symbolize based on the new field.  You can use the commas or length to calculate the value with Python

Comment: I made this field already, but it is not exactly what I want. There are 180 stations and I want a different color for each. If there is a zip code with multiple stations I want the exact color of these stations in the polygon. This way, you can see which zip code is delivered by which station in a single glance.

Comment: you are going to have to make another field based on the values of the first one. You can't symbolize based on multiple values in one field.  It's not the way it works. Symbology needs a single value